# Django does not save timestamp in UTC inside database (Postgres)

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone, models

in settings.py I have:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

and in model.py:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    creation_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: timezone.localtime(timezone.now()))
```

localtime is set according to user timezone using a Middleware and in this case is 'Europe/Rome' (so +0200).

When I create a new Game instance using Django admin creation_timestamp is automatically set to `2014-04-11 12:46:59+02` inside the form input displayed inside the page, but when I save 
it and I check the database I get `2014-04-11 12:46:59+02` which is not what I expect since, according to documentation, Django should cast all timestamps to UTC before saving. (I check database data using pgAdmin, not Django admin).

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can set PostgreSQL client parameter timezone to UTC. 
or set it in postgresql.conf, and then reload or send SIGHUP signal to postmaster pid.
timezone use exp :

```
digoal=# set timezone='UTC';
SET
digoal=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2014-04-11 13:53:12.903336+00
(1 row)

digoal=# set timezone='PRC';
SET
digoal=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2014-04-11 21:53:24.239343+08
(1 row)
```